# rsync incremental as a get

Tags: linux, rsync, incremental-backup, backup

Is it possible for rsync to be used on 1 backup server and then connect to all the other servers and grab files and backup incrementally?

my current command: (how ever this is more a PUT then a GET)

```
rsync -avz -e ssh /home yourusername@yourusername.bqbackup.com:server1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use your command the other way round from your backup server:

```
rsync -avz  user@targetmachine1:/home /path/to/targetmachine1
```

and with adapted paths for more than one machine.